# Where should I add/modify environment variables?

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

I would like to edit my `.bash_profile` file. However it appears that in Ubuntu (and perhaps other Debian distros) this is named as `.profile`.

However I cannot seem to find the expected variables like $PATH, $PS  etc. in the `.profile file`.  The `.bashrc` file doesn't seem to do any good either.

I am wondering how I can possibly modify my environment variables in this case.

Comment: Shell startup files tend to be on the far side of "distro-specific". Or near side, depending on which side you're on.

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/profile`? It is sourced first...

Comment: @jasonwryan yes I did. In my '/etc/' there is a file  named 'profile' which is documented as '/etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))' but I do not see any explicit assignment of environment variables. There is also a `profile.d` directory but it doesn't seem to have anything useful.

Comment: Probably I should add I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables), they do not recommend using `~/.profile`, instead they recommend using `~/.pam_environment` for adding items to $PATH:

> ~/.pam_environment - This file is specifically meant for setting a user's environment. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.
>
> ```
> PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/MyPrograms
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your environment variables such as $PATH or $PS permanently for bash sessions in your `.bashrc` file that is your `$HOME` directory.

if you need to set it permanently, and system wide (all users, all processes) add set variable in `/etc/environment`

Comment: You really should set environment variables in `.bash_profile`: see http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile